# Finding the Fourier Coefficients

Tags: fourier-series

[image]

Up until now, I have dealt with finding Fourier Coefficients for functions: $f(t) > 0$ 

Which made it convenient calculating the Fourier Analysis Integral. However, I am now presented with functions: $f(t) < 0$ 
My question is, would I need 3 different **bounds** when performing integration for this particular function?

i.e. For the function above, if the lower bound was limited to 0, I would only need to define the integration from -1 to 1 to fully represent the Fouier Analysis Integral: $ \int_{-1}^{1} 1$$ (e)^{-jwkt} $$ \,dt$

However, since the lower bound reaches to -1, would I need 3 different bounds of integration to fully represent and calculate the Fourier Analysis Integral / Coefficients?

Are there any easier "tricks"  for finding the Fourier coefficients?

Comment: The sign of the values of $f(t)$ don't play a role at all in how many integrals you need - the Fourier transform here is really just a one-dimensional integral transform, so you would need a single integral, if that exists. It's really not clear what you mean with the integrals! Please expand your question by editing to illustrate what you mean

Comment: I have edited the post! Thanks for clarifying my concept. I think you might have answered my question indirectly if what I asked above is correct.

Comment: You talk about the "Fourier Analysis Integral".  I haven't run across that name before.  Are you attempting to find the **Fourier Series** of this waveform, or are you attempting to find the **Fourier Transform** of it?  At any rate, that's a periodic function with a period of 4.  If you don't take any of the symmetry shortcuts, that means you need to integrate over the interval $t \in [t_0,\ t_0+4]$ for just about any $t_0$.

Comment: (Anyone who's about to critique me for using a doubly-closed interval -- yes, you're right.  I had a choice between exactly right and simple; I chose simple.)

Comment: I'm attempting to utilize **Fourier Series**  to find the **Fourier Coefficients**. You mentioned that the function has a period of 4, and that I should integrate over any interval t, t+4 - which I agree. I guess my true question would be, how would you describe the function? I've sort of answered my own question thanks to your first comment, but I was asking if its valid to think that: since integration is a linear operation, I am able to "create" a piecewise function that describes the "above" function, and take respective integration over those piecewise "bounds".

Comment: @JellyTree: Your last comment shows that you've understood what to do. Now try to realize that it's totally irrelevant whether $f(t)>0$ or not. That's why your question was a bit confusing. It's all about how to integrate a piecewise defined function.

Comment: @JellyTree I think I agree with Matt: The question you ask here in the comments – can I, and if so, how, piece together the Fourier transform from piecewise integrals – is pretty different from what you wrote in the question. I think it'd be best if you edited this question, and introduced a canonical notation for what you want to do. Your question (I hope I understand it correctly, I'm not 100% sure) seems to be a good one, and you might be pretty close to what the DFT actually is, theoretically. (To foreshadow: the FT of a single rectangle is a sinc. A rectangle wave has a line spectrum!)